# Pass arbitrary number of a set of variables to Python Function

Tags: python, arguments, user-defined-functions, function-calls

I am not sure on the precise way to phrase the question as it is easier to just demonstrate with code.  I would like to have a function that accepts a variable number of a set of 3 required and 1 optional arguments.  As an illustration, `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` can accept any number of `(x, y, color)` set of variables.  I would like to copy this behavior, but I am unsure of the proper way to do this using *args or similar.  Below I illustrate the behavior I would like.

```
myFunc(name, lo, hi, step) # Do something
myFunc(name, lo, hi, step, name2, low2, hi2, step2) # Do something for name and name2
myFunc(name, lo, hi, name2, low2, hi2) # Same as above but use default step for both
```

The only way I can think of is to loop through the arguments and perform a series of checks on make sure it satisfies the type for `(name, lo, hi, step)` and to check if `step` is even given, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Edit:

I wanted the above behavior since my function uses the first set to identify a parameter and create a while loop.  If any more sets of parameters remain it calls itself recursively to construct a nested while loop with the remaining parameters, etc.  If no additional sets remain it will perform some data measurement and then return.  This way I can loop through an arbitrarily large multi-dimensional space using a single recursive function.

Comment: Perhaps you want **kwargs.  These will allow you optional keyword arguments

Comment: There are parts of the `matplotlib` api that I find to be really awful -- This is one of them.  :-).  In this case, I'd recommend having the function/method called a number of times with 3 required and 1 optional argument. . . Would that be possible for your use case?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: I might be able to just use *args since the recursive nature of the function means I only have to check the first 4 args and then see if any more exist.

Comment: In response to your edit -- why have the user pass an iterable of `(name, low, hi, [step])`?

Comment: I use name to identify which parameter, and the rest specify the array of values for that parameter.  I may want to perform some measurement on every point in x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] or every point in 2d grid of x, y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], or every point in a 6d grid where I have 6 parameters each has a unique array of points.

My other thought is to make a big numpy grid array, but for each point in the phase space I need a particular measurement function run and I'm not sure how to do this with numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
list_of_things = [('name', 'lo', 'hi', 'step'),
                  ('name2', 'lo2', 'hi2'), 
                  ('name3', 'lo3', 'hi3', 'step3')
]
def myFunc(name, lo, hi, step='default'):
                              # do something
def callMyFunc(x):    
    for i in x:
        myFunc(*i)            # pass the contents of the tuple as arguments
```

If you don't want the tuple of items ordered, you would have to name each of the arguments and submit them named.

Comment: Sort of, but I need the for loop inside the function, so to speak.  Basically I check how many of the tuples I have, and the function changes depending on how many have been passed.  More specifically it processes the first set and if any more tuples remain I recursively call the function.

Comment: I've edited it to place the for loop inside of a second function. Calling that function with the list will process each tuple inside one by one. Based on your updated question, this may not help.